# is there a good practice Redirect with PHP, that allows to display <BODY> content?

Tags: php

I've read somewhere that using a META refresh for a redirect, is not a recommended practice.

As far as I understand `header( "refresh:0;url=$url" );` in PHP,
and `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=$url/" />`as a META tag in HTML,
are both considered a META refresh which would return this header:

```
HTTP/1.x 200 OK
...
Refresh: 0;url=$url
```

Assuming I don't want to use a JS redirect, would it be possible to use another recommended practice redirect such as 301 or 302, while still running the following elements in the redirect page, such as the following message and a certain script?

```
<?php
$url = "could-not-get-a-foo-parameter-at-all-error-monitoring-page.html"; 

if(isset($_POST['foo'])){

    switch ($_POST['foo']) {

    case "a":
        $url = "http://www.aaa.com/";
        break;

    case "b":
        $url = "http://www.bbb.com/";
        break;

    default:
        $url = "foo-parameter-exists-but-is-wrong-error-monitoring-page.html";
        break;
    }
}

header( "refresh:0;url=$url" );

?>  
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
.message {
   color:blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="message">Redirecting, Please hold on...</div>
<script>
something
</script>
```

Comment: No, there is no reason to display body content when issuing a HTTP 3xx redirect because the user-agent (browser) will immediately request the next resource (given by the `Location:` header).

Comment: Hey @rockyraw! Good to see you posting nearly the same question again.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I beg to differ, it's a similar code, but not really same question

Comment: I said "nearly". ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

You can't invoke PHP once the page has rendered (no more PHP until another server request), so any form of delayed redirect is impossible that way. You're stuck with JS or the meta header refresh (obviously, you can't use PHP variables in pure HTML and you need more than 0 seconds if you actually want to keep the page up for a while before redirecting).

Comment: Your answer is patently false.

Comment: @TML Tell me more, you *can* invoke PHP after it's done rendering the page you're viewing?

Comment: You don't need to "invoke PHP after it's done rendering the page you're viewing" to get the desired effect. See my answer.

Comment: Everything in the question can be accomplished using a refresh value of something other than '0'. The body content will be displayed until the timeout is reached.

Comment: @TML OP obviously knows about it. Let me spell it for you: "would it be possible to use **another** recommended practice..." **Another**. Get it? And to that I reply: "You're stuck with JS or the meta header refresh...".

Comment: "Use a value other than 0" fits "another recommended practice" in my book.

Comment: Withdrew the -1 since OP clarified that "using a different timeout" does not answer his question.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer. No.

a PHP header redirect, `<?php header('location: [url]');?>` will give you the 302 header, which the browser will redirect to, but you cannot also send HTML that will ever be seen by the user since as soon as the browser sees that header, it will immediately redirect and won't display the rest of the content.
you CAN change the timeout on the meta redirect as suggested by TML, but that will leave the page up until the timed interval has passed, or you can create a interstitial page with your message, and let them know how long until the redirect happens, with an option to click "here" now for an immediate redirect.

Comment: I believe OP wants the page to be up for a while.

Comment: @Shomz I don't want the redirect page to be up for a while, only about a second, enough to display a "redirecting you" message and to execute a tracking JS script

Comment: what's an interstitial page? isn't that exactly what I'm already doing here?

Comment: @rockyraw Yes, I understand, by "up for a while" I meant "not redirecting instantly". Didn't want to imply a long period of time, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use all 3 options as it will gracefully degrade.

1. Meta-refresh. (Works with JS disabled)
2. JS location redirect. (Allows more control than meta-refresh, snappy)
3. Static HTML anchor. (Backup for those that want content faster than the refresh)

Not sure if it's still an issue but some browsers wouldn't send a referer header for 0 second meta-refresh and instead needed a little time to set it.

Comment: 1) The thing is that I am reluctant (for my own reasons) to have the url anywhere in the source code of the page, meaning my only option is probably have the URL sent in the header only. 2) do you mean that for safety measures, I should always use at least a `1` second as the interval? 3. what do you mean by more control and snappy?

Comment: 1) Without the URL, the browser can't know where to go. No matter what method the URL will always be exposed to the client. 2) Well it's an old bug, 1 second was the fix, not sure current status but safe to put some time in there. 3) JS gives you an opportunity to work with the URL on the client and responds instantly when you decide to do the redirect, gives you more functionality than a meta-refresh, but the meta-refresh works when JS is disabled.

Comment: 1) the browser would know if get the info through the sent headers, rather then from the source of the page.. no? I mean that's what my current code does exactly. 2) so your'e saying a 0 sec JS redirect would work faster than a 0 sec meta refresh? how significant can this be for my visitors? and out of curiosity, since only one redirect can take place, which one do you suggest as a fallback (JS/META) and in what interval should it be set?

Comment: hmm not certain on meta-refresh vrs JS and who wins... Block loading of the page might see the meta-refresh wait until at least the headers are fully loaded, where JS would just fire off once it's block is loaded, likely would all depend on where they're positioned and which ends up fully loading into the DOM first.... I just use all methods in combination.

Answer (score -2):

Use a refresh value of something other than 0:
`header( "refresh:10;url=$url" );`

Comment: Tell the OP why the refresh value has to be different.

Comment: since that's not an answer to real topic of the question (which is about a recommended alternative redirection method), I suppose that's a comment? can you explain why other than 0?

Comment: If what you want is to "display the body and run some javascript", giving a time of something other than zero will do exactly that. The '0' is the number of seconds the UA will wait before following the refresh URL.

Comment: @TML I'm looking for an alternative redirection method that would do the same. the current 0 interval _does_ display the message and execute the script.